# call prototype.call function in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

the problem is that when i use test.call(), it calls into my call implementation of the prototype but when i use test(), it doesnt call call(). i want to be able to use test to trigger prototype.call(). code below:

```
            Function.prototype.call = function () {
            //do something...
            return this(); // call original method
        }

        function test() {
            alert("test");
        }

 test.call(); //calls prototype.call()
    test(); //doesnt call prototype.call()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that I just whipped up (credit goes to **cliffsofinsanity** for pointing out a crucial error with the code and correcting it). It logs all non-standard functions called after a certain point, in the order that they were called.

```
// array of all called functions
var calledFunctions = [];

// custom func object that has name of function and 
// and the actual function on it.

function func(_func, name) {
    return function() {
        calledFunctions.push(name)
        return _func.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

test = function() {
    alert("hi");
}

otherTest = function() {
    alert("hello");
}

// put this bit somewhere after you've defined all your functions
// but *before* you've called any of them as all functions called
// after this point are logged. It logs all non-standard functions
// in the order that they are called.
for (prop in window) {
    if (window.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof window[prop] === 'function' && window[prop].toString().indexOf('[native code]') < 0) {
        window[prop] = func(window[prop], prop);
    }
}

otherTest();
test();
otherTest();

console.log(calledFunctions);​
```

Working demo can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TkZ6d/10/).

Comment: Keep in mind that any arguments passed to the functions are lost, as well as the return value, and the context of the function may be altered. You should do `return that._func.apply(this, arguments);`. Also, you could really do this without a constructor. You're having to close over `that` to reference `_func` and `name` as properties, so instead you could skip the `that` object, and just close over the parameters. http://jsfiddle.net/TkZ6d/10/

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for pointing that out! I've edited my answer and given you credit.

Comment: just wondering what that means: window[prop].toString().indexOf('[native code]') < 0

Comment: @AliTarhini: It converts a property of the window to a string representation then checks to see if the string `"[native code]"` is found. If it is, then the property is something's "native" or standard to Javascript.

Comment: thanks. The above code work perfectly. Is it possible to get script that is not embedded inside a function such as inline scripts that are writen directly inside script tags?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you include the `for (prop in window)` somewhere after you declare them. I'm actually thinking about making this a plugin and if that's the case I'll have something for you in a day or two, such that you can go something like `log.logFunctions` and then `log.stopLogging` or something like that. =)

Answer (score 2):

Why would you expect `test()` to invoke `Function.prototype.call`? They're different functions.

The native `.call()` method that you're overwriting is not invoked every time a function is invoked. It's only invoked when *you* invoke it.

Invoking `.call()` does invoke `test()` because that's what it's designed to do. It expects a function as its context (`this` value), and invokes that function. But that doesn't mean `.call()` has anything to do with any other function invocation.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. So how is it possible to do it. I need to call a function whenever any other function is invoked.

Comment: It is simply not possible. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @AliTarhini: Not automatically. You could manually decorate the functions, but you'd need foreknowledge of those functions.

Comment: I need to create a log of all functions being executed

Comment: Sounds like a job for a debugger.

Comment: Is it possible using debug.js ?

Comment: @AliTarhini: Is your code running in a browser? Most browsers have developer tools built in. They'll let you step through the code as it executes. I assume this is ultimately what you want.

Comment: Actually I need to programatically create an array with the names of the functions that are being executed.

Comment: @AliTarhini: Every function, or just a set that's of particular interest to you? And I'd be curious to know what the Array is to be used for. Is it to exclude unused functions from the download?

Comment: Yes every function. This is just for educational purpose

Comment: Then no, there's really no way to automatically do that. You'd need to replace every function with one that logs then calls the original. It may not even be possible with certain host functions.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Yes, except that OP wanted every function, not just non-standard ones. But your answer would be something similar to what would need to be done. There are a couple issues with your code, but I'll post them under your answer.